# intersecting two matrix in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have two matrix. Both are `nx2` with values column 1 has id and column 2 has values:

```
| id1 | A1 |
| id2 | A2 |
| id3 | A3 |
| id4 | A4 |
```

First one represents data about object `A` and second one represents data about object `B`. I need to find common ids from both matrix and put them into a single matrix with just values:

```
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B2 |
| A3 | B3 |
| A4 | B4 |
```

Condition being each row represents values corresponding to same id. Important: Ignore all ids which are not common to both input matrix. My data set is long and I am looking at best way to accomplish it in octave (similar solution would work with matlab as well I guess). Ids in a single matrix are unique.

**Note**: I forgot to mention earlier that id's (for a single matrix) are unique to a matrix but they don't represent row numbers and numbers with no meaning.

Comment: yes ids are unique in a matrix. I will add that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most easily accomplished with `intersect`:

```
[uniqueIDs, idxA, idxB] = intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1));

result = [A(idxA,2),B(idxB,2)]
```